# Search string in if statement only matches some of the items

Tags: python-2.7

This only produces a small list of items returned it matches, when there are many more that match. findit contains the search string that is converted to lower case. The list of files are also converted to lower case.

```
home_dir_path = "/home/share/DUMMY_DATA"    # Development data
full_path_original = ""
regex_string = "^" + home_dir_path + "/"

# Enter all or part of the file name to search:             
if submit_search is not None:
    print "<h1>Searching for: " + findit + "</h1>"  
    # Convert search_string to lower case for compare.
    search_string = findit.lower()          
    for path, directories, files in os.walk(home_dir_path):
        for file in files:
            full_path_original = os.path.join(path, file)
            full_path_display = re.sub(regex_string, "", full_path_original)
            full_path = full_path_display.lower()
            if search_string in full_path:
                print full_path_display + "<br>"
```

If I do a print of full_path before the last if statement, it lists every file, so it seems the if search_string isn't working. But it is matching a couple dozens of them where there are a couple of hundred that should be displayed.

Is there another approach I should be using than 'if search_string in full_path:' ?

Here is some sample data I put together to reproduce the problem.

```
find . | grep -i alpha
./alpha
./alpha/resume
./alpha/a
./alpha/b
./alpha/c
./alpha/d
./alpha/e
./alpha/f
./alpha/.hidden_file_test
./Alpha
./alphA
./alphA/stuff
./AlPha
./AlPha/.hidden_nothing
```

The above code being used to search for "alpha" in the same directory as the above returns this:

```
Searching for: alpha
alpha/f
alpha/f
alphA/stuff
AlPha/.hidden_nothing
AlPha/.hidden_nothing
AlPha/.hidden_nothing
```

It is a subset of what is there, and it contains duplicates.

Comment: Can you give some sample input, along with actual and expected output?

Comment: I wish I could, it's on the company intranet and I can't share it. But an example would be a single word search like the word 'resume' it should return any string which has 'resume' in it. But it is only returning some of them.

Comment: Let me dummy up some data to reproduce the problem!

Comment: @glibdud Please see above, I updated it with sample output.

Comment: So your desired result is to reproduce the grep? Find any files with `findit` anywhere in the full (relative) path, case insensitive?

Comment: @glibdud Yes, exactly.

Comment: I can't reproduce your result. The only thing it's missing when I run it is directories, and that's because you're only checking `files`.

Comment: @glibdud Thanks for doing that. Is there another or better approach to coding this I should try?

Comment: I think you should check if `yourString` is in `directories` too. You are only check if it's in `fileName` now